# How do I copy values in multiple columns merging each row value into another with a comma as delimiter with script leaving original Data intact?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have too many Array formulas slowing down my sheet and I want to try using some script to replace some of them.
Currently I am using this to accomplish one of the tasks:

This is in A7

```
=arrayformula("#"&O7:O&""&S7:S&","&AD7:AD&","&AE7:AE&","&AF7:AF&","&AG7:AG)
```

This is my poor attempt.

```
function onEdit() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

    var range1 = sheet.getRange("AD7:AF");
    range1.getValues();
    var range2 = sheet.getRange("AG7:AG");
    range2.setValues();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that should produce the same result as putting `=arrayformula("#"&O7:O&""&S7:S&","&AD7:AD&","&AE7:AE&","&AF7:AF&","&AG7:AG)` into A7. But to be faster than formulas you would have to replace not just one but many formulas by one single script.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheets()[0],
      range1 = sheet.getRange("O7:AG"),
      range2 = sheet.getRange("A7:A"),
      values1 = range1.getValues(),
      values2 = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
    var row = values1[i];
    values2.push(["#"+row[0]+row[4]+","+row[15]+","+row[16]+","+row[17]+","+row[18]]);
  }

  range2.setValues(values2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Im creating calendar events in a spread sheet if anyone would like to take a look https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iTXdw-itHAZDl4JXdm7ZeYfNtEX-TdheI3mPMNdeeoQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I edited my answer. My range was not quite right. btw. you know that your spreadsheet can be edited by anyone?

Comment: Yes, its just a copy i think you and I are the only people looking at it right now. I only just changed the permissions so you could see what I am trying to do.

Comment: The code you added to this for me is giving an incorrect range height error , would you @SpiderPig mind taking a look?                                                    for(var i = 0; i < values1.length && values1[i][0]  !== ""; i++){

Comment: `values2` and `values3` were too small. They need to have the same size as the corresponding ranges. I changed it.

Comment: Thanks im going to try adding to it.

Comment: Seems to work great. Is there a limit to how many ranges I can use?